# Wrong NPM version in visual code [npx create-react-app]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I am not sure why but I am having an annoying issue with my VSCode and NPM version. I am trying to create a new npx create-react-app . but VSCode displays the following error:

```
You are using npm 2.15.12 so the project will be bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.

Please update to npm 5 or higher for a better, fully supported experience.
```

however this is not true:

The latest version of NPM is 6.14.2 and node is v12.16.1

I am stuck because I cannot create react apps.

Can somebody help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of NPM is installed on your system? Check using `npm -v` in cmd. Check node version as well `node -v`

Comment: NPM is 6.14.2 and node is v12.16.1 in my system

Comment: Your system can have multiple versions of node installed. Check out `nvm` to manage which version to use

Comment: Rodolfo AC@DESKTOP-NQPLDNN MINGW64 ~
$ nvm list

  * 12.16.1 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

Rodolfo AC@DESKTOP-NQPLDNN MINGW64 ~
$

Comment: The VSCode is displaying the same error.